# Spring batch mechanism for CORBA

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, corba

Is there an established way a CORBA client API could be invoked part of the Spring-Batch mechanism?

I have a requirement for mass data be processed through the APIs hosted via CORBA from a database. I am considering the API call as an Item Processor or Item Writer.

For Item processor, I may need to just call the API in the processing phase by injecting the necessary CORBA stuff.

For Item Writer, Is there a writer that is suitable? I didn't find one. Maybe I can build a writer generically so that it could be used as any other writer or just write a custom writer and get over it.

Could anyone help by evaluating the approaches and suggest the best possible way?
If I could write a generic CorbaItemWriter how can I contribute to the Spring Batch community?

Note: I was able to successfully get the CORBA client configured in Spring and use the ItemProcessor to connect the API.

Answer (score 1):

There is no CORBA based `ItemWriter` (or `ItemReader` for that matter) so you'll need to write your own.  With regards to contributing it to the core framework, you can follow the guidelines for creating a contribution here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: I have got this implemented the above. As you know CORBA is similar to calling another java method, the key is to ensure the connection to the server is as long as possible within its load tolerance, hence chunk is used to monitor this. I have an issue in persisting the skipped application exception from the server. When the server has processed say 90 records successfully out of a chunk of 100 an application exception for the 91st record means all the 90 are processed again and resulting in 91 Exceptions (90 are duplicates now for the server) as against 1. Any solution to this?

Comment: Please ask this as a new question and I can respond there.

Comment: Thank, posted as a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803856/spring-batch-for-corba-issue-with-transactions-retry-mechanism